# Object is required

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a checkbox in the Word and perform function when the check box is clicked but I am getting an error as "Object is required".
I have given name of check box as 'CheckBox1' and macro function as 'CheckBox1_Click'. When the check box is cliked I want to update the table row with text.

```
Public Sub CheckBox1_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim tbl As Table
Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    'Update Table2 Row 7 with ""
    tbl.Cell(7, 1).Range.Text = "input1"
Else
    'Clear the contents of Table2 Row 7
    tbl.Cell(7, 1).Range.Text = ""
End If

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: When I debug, 'If CheckBox1.Value = True Then' This line is causing the error but a name for the checkbox is 'CheckBox1'.

Comment: Are you sure that CheckBox1 exists in ActiveDocument? Try to replace ActiveDocument with ThisDocument (document in which macro and CheckBox1 exists).

Comment: You have tagged this with `excel`. What does the question have to do with `excel`?

Comment: Your code should work if the checkbox and code are in a userform. If the checkbox is on the document, you'll need different code. This code will depend on whether the checkbox is a FormField, ActiveX or Content Control. For a FormField, use: If ActiveDocument.FormFields("CheckBox1").CheckBox.value = "True"

Comment: @JohnKorchok The checkbox is on the document. Checkbox is content control .